# Integration Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to solve $\displaystyle \quad \int\frac{dz}{1+5z^2}$

and Wolfram says I need to use the substitution with inverse tan, taking $u=\sqrt{5}z$, giving me $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\int\frac{du}{1+u^2}.$$

Surely this is incorrect as the 1 in the demoninator would now be $\sqrt{5}$ too. What don't I understand?

Comment: After substituting, you get $\int {1\over 1+u^2}\cdot\underbrace{{1\over\sqrt5}\,du}_{dz}$. You then factor $1/\sqrt 5$ out of the integral. The denominator of ${1\over 1+u^2}$ does not come into play here.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me see it a lot more clearly. Thank you to everyone.

Answer (score 5):

If $\;u = \sqrt{5}z\;$ then $\;du = \sqrt{5}\, dz \;\implies\; \color{red}{\bf{dz = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt5}} \,du}\;$ and

$$\int\frac{1}{1+5z^2}\,dz = \int \frac{1}{1 + (\sqrt{5}z)^2} \,\color{red}{\bf dz}=  \int\frac{1}{1+u^2} \cdot \color{red}{\bf{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\,du}}\; = \;\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \int \dfrac{1}{1+u^2}\,du \;= \;\;?$$

Answer (score 1):

$du=\sqrt 5 dz$, you have to account for this when substituting

Comment: So they cancel out and the 1 remains as 1 right?

Comment: exactly, but I would recommend doing the integrals on paper until you are comfortable with them